# Understanding the proof on why the first cohomology group of a Galois extension is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, galois-theory, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Currently, I am trying to understand the following theorem with its proof (taken from [Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory*, page 70](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf)):

[image]

As you can see, I am questioning the well-definedness of the sum for the case when $G$ is infinite.

> **Question**: Did the author implicity assumed that $G$ is finite or is this argument still valid for an infinite Galois group $G$?

Also, or those of you who are curious what *Corollary 5.15* is:

[image]

Comment: For an infinite Galois extension one would take $G$ to be a profinite group acting continuously on $E^\times$ as a discrete module. In this context the cohomology is the direct limit of the cohomology of finite extensions, so Hilbert 90 would still hold.

Comment: Yes, the author is assuming that $G$ is finite here.